# Extracting regular expressions containing characters such as \, < etc in RStudio, using grep

Tags: r

I have a list in Rstudio looking like this:

```
head(linesofinterest)

Chinese in Speech and Writing 1

1 "Di\u0300 yi\u0304 jia\u030cng Lecture 1 \u7b2c\u4e00\u8bb2"     
2 "1. Chinese Pronounciation (1) pp.1-10* \u2022 Initials & finals"
3 4. Grammar and Language Practice pp.22-26                        
4 * Please read the assigned pages in your textbook.               
5 Homework (Due 23:59                                              
6 2. Watch KI1046 Chinese pronunciation drills.mp4 (on Learn)
```

Now I want to extract the rows containing a backslash, but when I try it using this code, it doesn't work:

> linesofinterest <- Kinesiska_lektioner[grepl("\u", Kinesiska_lektioner$`Chinese in Speech and Writing 1`,fixed = TRUE),]

I get the following error message:

> Error: '\u' used without hex digits in character string starting ""\u"

Is it because I am looking for a kind of character that means something else when written like this?

Tried to search and find an answer here on stackoverflow that I could understand but didn't succeed, hence my question.

Thanks and all the best,
Pontus

Comment: `\u0300` is a Unicode character, not a literal `\u`.  Are you looking to find lines which have a Unicode character in them?

Comment: Yes that is correct. What I want to do is basically to find all the Chinese characters used in a course I am taking to learn Chinese :)

Comment: Do you know exactly what these Chinese characters are?  Do you want _all_ Chinese characters, or just a subset of them?

Comment: So what I did is the following:
I copied all the PFD-slides given for the course in to a txt-document and read it into R. These PDF-slides contains the Chinese characters as they should be written, i.e. 你好 etc, but when I copy them to a txt file and import a txt file into R studio they get displayed as Unicode, i.e. 第一 is Di<U+0300> yi<U+0304> and so on.

So my idea was to extract all the patterns like this: 
"<U+" but that didn't work, then I noticed that when I search for specific rows in the list, they are not displayed like "<U+" but rather like \u4e2d\u6587 etc.

Comment: I have no idea if this is the right way to approach it, never use R for text mining otherwise, just wanted to try for fun.